# Django South migration error "contains null values" with null=True field

Tags: django, django-south

When adding a field for easy-thumbnails to a model

```
easy_thumbnail = ThumbnailerImageField(
    null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Easy_Thumbnails"),
    upload_to="easy_thumbnails",
    resize_source=dict(size=(100, 100), crop="smart"),
)
```

When executing `./manage.py schemamigration test --auto`, South produces the following migration:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Adding field 'Test.easy_thumbnail'
    db.add_column('test_test', 'easy_thumbnail', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField')(), keep_default=False)
[...]
models = {
    'test.test': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'Test'},
        'easy_thumbnail': ('django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField', [], {}),
```

When executing `./manage.py migrate test`, I got this error:

```
The error is `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "easy_thumbnail" contains null values`
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the migration script as follows solves the problem:

- Adding "null=True, blank=True" in db.add_column
- Adding "'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'" in models['test.test']['easy_thumbnail']

The code:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Adding field 'Test.easy_thumbnail'
    db.add_column('test_test', 'easy_thumbnail', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField')(null=True, blank=True), keep_default=False)
[...]
models = {
    'test.test': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'Test'},
        'easy_thumbnail': ('django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
```

Comment: This is first step. In second step. You should set old data to sensible defaults and in third step, remove the null values...if this is what make sense in Your application, of course.

Comment: What matters here is that south doesn't define the new column with allowing null and blank as defined in the model.